How can I start a local VMware machine without bringing the VMware Workstation window to the foreground?
I'm starting my VMWare machines, using the vmrun.exe command, i.e vmrun.exe start vmpath but this brings the VMWare Workstation window to the foreground, i would like to avoid this.
Using the nogui option i.e vmrun.exe start vmpath nogui it doesn't activate the VMWare Workstation window, however, this hides the machine tab on the worsktation window .
I dont want to hide anything, i'm trying to automatize starting the machines on the background while still having their tabs there and without bringing any window to the foreground.
Does someone know if/how this could be achieved?
I'm on Win10, workstation 17.6.
